# nodejs http server works on port 3333 but https refuse connection. While testing on localhost works fine

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl, https, digital-ocean

I have two nodejs web servers running on digitalocean in the same droplet. One is for frontend react https server (on port 443) another one is for the backend API https server (on port 3333). Testing these localhost works fine (i have an SSL certificate from sslforfree.com ). But on digitalocean the backend API requests are always timed out. While changing the backend server to the http server (express) it works again. Can anyone help me find what causing this behavior? Here's my server generation code :

`````
// initialize server

//https_conf 
var https_conf = {
    key : fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname,"/config/ssl/private.key")),
    cert : fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname,"/config/ssl/certificate.crt")),
    ca : fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname,"/config/ssl/ca_bundle.crt")),
}

var app      = express();
/*var server   = app.listen(w_server_config.port,function(){
                        console.log(`listening on port ${w_server_config.port}`);
                    })*/

var server   = https.createServer(https_conf,app).listen(w_server_config.port,function(){
                        console.log(` https server is listening on port ${w_server_config.port}`)
})
var io       = require('socket.io')(server);

````
`````

Comment: Can you share you NGINX config, please? All `https` requests are going to 443 port by default, so if there is no other proxying, your request will be directed to the wrong location

Comment: it's a ubuntu machine no nginx. the servers are nodejs https servers. I'm not sure whether there is any proxy in set

Comment: Well, you should try to use NGINX, where in config file you can proxy request from, let's say, `https://yourdomain.com/api/**` (which is served with 443 port by default) to `localhost:3333/**`. Or you should manually set your port in api request at frontend, e.g. `https://yourdomain.com:3333/api/**`